# How to count number of digits in a number in oracle pl/sql?

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I need to modify number which is having more than 5 digits.LENGTH function is for string but not for number of digits.What should be done to count the digits in a number?

Comment: Integers, or might you have to deal with decimals too - and if so how would you count those?

Comment: It would be helpful if you state *why* you need the length. e.g. is it for working out the number of characters needed to format it for display or storage (e.g. in a text file)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
select length(to_char(11111)) from dual
```

Output  5

Answer (score 0):

`length` is fine, with an implicit or explicit `to_char()` to convert the number to a string whose characters can then be counted, as OldProgrammer showed.

If you want to treat it as a number you could also do:

```
trunc(1/log(n, 10)) + 1
```

... which works for integers above 2. But that's going to be rather less intuitive for someone trying to maintain your code later...

Comment: Why do you suggest doing the reverse conversion of the logarithm? I suggest a more correct version: `CASE 
  WHEN TRUNC(n) = 0 THEN 1 
  ELSE FLOOR(log(10, ABS(TRUNC(n)))) +1
  END`

Answer (score -1):

When not just keep things simple?

CASE WHEN mynumber >= 100000 THEN whatever;

Comment: Until what number?